# Android databinding using in different modules

Tags: android, layout, data-binding, module, include

Now I have three modules,module A ,B,C.module A compile module B,module B compile module C.There is a layout(layout_c.xml) in module C.Then I using layout_c.xml in module A's layout(layout_a.xml).

1. there is layout_c.xml
   `

   ```
   </variable>

   <variable
       name="handler"
       type="xxxxxx">

   </variable>
   ```

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       ......
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

   `
2. there is layout_a.xml

   `<include
        android:id="@+id/layout_c"
        layout="@layout/layout_c"/>`
3. question:IDE think bindingA.layoutC return a view not a databinding.And module C has BR class and all databinding class.But module A doesn't have.So,what should I do?

   `LayoutABinding bindingA = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.layout_a);
   newTitleBarViewModel.setDataBinding(bindingA.layoutC);`

Comment: Hmm the compilation should work. Did you try compiling and see what the generated LayoutABinding class has? I'm wondering if this is a studio bug.
Also, if so, can you file a bug on b.android.com w/ a sample project attached. Thanks.

Comment: No,LayoutABinding class not generated.Only C module has LayoutCBinding class. I think ,the reason why LayoutABinding not generated is the IDE compile failed.So it not generated.Do you think so?

Comment: I had create a sample project at the moment,but it also has this problem.So I will file a bug to them and wait reply.

Comment: can you add a link to the bug here ?

Answer (score 6):

In order to get data binding to work across multiple modules  - in my case -  I had to make sure that each Android Studio module (library, phone/tablet, etc) has data binding enabled in its corresponding `build.gradle` *(not just for the library .gradle file, as that was not enough)*,

like so:

```
android {
        ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    // Looks like this needs to be set in the app module that uses the lib
    // The lib needs it for the layout binding code there
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}
```

---

The project structure where solution is applied :

1. There is a **library module**, and multiple **"app modules"** *(aka, Android Studio module for Phone or Tablet that can be run)* that use Activities/layouts from that library in the same project
2. The library project has .xml under /res/layout that relies on data binding, like so:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/display_name_text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:text="@={user.displayName}"
       android:textSize="20sp"/>
   ```

---

> This one was a bit tricky to resolve.  Especially in my case where I have multiple modules.  After I applied this solution for the main module I was working with, I still continued getting build errors.  Finally I noticed in all the error output that there was 1 other module - which I hadn't been working with - that also had the library as dependency , but was missing the data binding enable in `build.gradle`.  When finally that was identified and addressed, the builds are working fine.  *I'm glad to have found this as it makes things a lot nicer when you can reuse layouts with data binding across multiple modules*

Comment: Wondering why this is so. I'm experiencing a lot of weird errors since going multi-module. Seems like some transitive dependencies have to be added to the app module.