# ViewBinding- not working for child layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm currently updating the source code with the ViewBindings but I'm not getting them to work for child layouts of the other modules which was working previously. I'm on `Android Studio 4.1.3`. I  added `viewBinding.enabled = true` to app modules `build.gradle`. But when I try to access a button from the child layouts, it does not give any error but it does not perform the operation also.

*main_fragment.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">

<com.playerview.TestPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/testPlayerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:v3PlaybackEnabled="true"
    app:always_show_go_to_live="true"
    app:extra_overlay_layout = "@array/extra_overlays"
    app:server_side_ad_overlay_index = "1"
    app:hide_play_pause_on_live="true"
    app:show_partner_logo="true"
    app:hide_seek_controllers_on_live="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:show_subtitle_on_full_screen="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*FragmentBindingProvider.kt*

```
class FragmentBindingProvider private constructor(
val btnPlayNext: Button?,
val testPlayerView: TestPlayerView,
val txtPlaylistPosition: TextView?,
val btnMute: ToggleButton?,
private val root: View
) : ViewBinding {

override fun getRoot(): View = root

companion object {
    fun inflate(isLogoView: Boolean, inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): FragmentBindingProvider {
        return if (isLogoView) initLogo(inflater, container) else init(inflater, container)
    }

    private fun initLogo(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): FragmentBindingProvider {
        val binding = FragmentLogoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return FragmentBindingProvider(
            btnPlayNext = binding.btnPlayNext,
            testPlayerView = binding.testPlayerView,
            txtPlaylistPosition = binding.txtPlaylistPosition,
            btnMute = binding.testPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.btnMute),
            root = binding.root
        )
    }
  }
}
```

*player_video_controls.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible">

         <include
        android:id="@+id/player_volume_layout"
        layout="@layout/view_controls_volume"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/player_ad_volume_width"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_bar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottom_bar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*view_controls_volume.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:background="@color/transparent_black_percent_80">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMute"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/top_controls_icon_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/top_controls_icon_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_volume"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />

</FrameLayout>
```

*MainFragment.kt*

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    observeViewModel()

    /*Here calling view of child layout*/
    binding.btnMute?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { v, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked && binding.testPlayerView.isMuted()) {
            binding.testPlayerView.unmute()
        } else {
            binding.testPlayerView.mute()
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone gets idea please let me know.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60260556/4587527) answer of mine help?

Comment: No @SomeshKumar it didn't help

Comment: Did you try debugging your generated binding in runtime? If that button is null then it failed to find it by ID on the player view from binding. I assume you're using `player_video_controls` same way exoPlayer uses its controller layout. If that's the case try to put a breakpoint on the player view constructor and see if how it handles `player_video_controls`

Answer (score 0):

**Only answers the problem that the included layout is in another module:**

For a quick fix if the `player_video_controls.xml` is not in the same module as `player_video_controls.xml`, add it to the same module or instead of including it, add the layout itself (which is awful but it works).

But, if you have many instances of this issue I suggest you read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46961519/6464513) and try to enable ViewbBinding in every module of your project that is a direct or indirect dependency of the module with this problem.

Comment: I copied `player_video_controls.xml` in the app module from the ui module and renamed the file as well but still it's not working

Comment: You should use binding.playerVolumeLayout.btnMute to get a handle of ToggleButton.

Comment: Did it help you with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

bindig.playerVolumeLayout.btnMute your can access like this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
binding.testPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.btnMute),
```

In your FragmentBindingProvider.kt:

```
   binding.testPlayerView.btnMute
```

Because after you do `binding.btnMute?` and may be btnMute is null and setOnCheckedChangeListener won't be trigger.
If it's not the solution remove your `val btnMute: ToggleButton?` to `val btnMute: ToggleButton` and remove `binding.btnMute?` by `binding.btnMute`. But nromaaly viewbinding is null safe so you have a value for your button.